# show iframe when press html button does not work - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show an iframe only when I click a button using javascript, but it's not working and I have no idea why.

```js
//I tried this way. did not work.

document.querySelector(".buttonweek").addEventListener('click', function()      {ThisWeek();});

function ThisWeek(){
  document.querySelector("#week").style.display = "block";
}

//then I tried that way. did not work.

document.getElementById("idweek").addEventListener('click', function() {ThisWeek();});

function ThisWeek(){
  document.getElementById("week").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
iframe{
    display:none;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><button type="button" class="buttonweek" id="idweek">Hot This Week</button></li>
    
<iframe src="thisweek.php" id="week"></iframe>
</ul>
```

I also tried to use the onclick in the obstrusive way, it also did not work !!

If anyone has read this, thank you!

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser console? Problem is probably related to [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I've ran this code and it seems to work?

Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Live demos are great, but they need to be [mcve]s. It does not good to provide JS that depends on HTML and CSS without providing the HTML and CSS. It does not good to provide a demo with contains CSS and **only** CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should help you,

```js
window.onload = function(){

document.getElementById("idweek").addEventListener('click', function(){

document.getElementById("week").style.display = "block";

});

}
```

```css
iframe{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><button type="button" class="buttonweek"  id="idweek">Hot This Week</button></li>
    
<iframe src="thisweek.php" id="week"></iframe>
</ul>
```